# How to put multiple websites on a localhost port 80 using nginx.conf file?

Tags: nginx, localhost, virtualhost

I used nginx to setup a virtual server and have a `nginx.conf` file as below, which works fine for two different websites on `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:100`:

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
error_log /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/error.log;
pid       /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log    /usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log  /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/localhost.access.log  combined;

        location / {
            root   /Users/apiah/Websites/greenapple;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /Users/apiah/Websites/greenapple;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/apiah/Websites/greenapple$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       100;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log  /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/localhost.access.log  combined;

        location / {
            root   /Users/apiah/Websites/blueweb;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /Users/apiah/Websites/blueweb;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/apiah/Websites/blueweb$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }    
}
```

I like to test the above two (or more) websites on the same port 80 `http://localhost`. For example, assume that we have three folders called `blueweb`, `redweb` and `greenweb`, so I want to be able to see all three folders when I go to `http://localhost` and then from there choose to go to `http://localhost/blueweb`, `http://localhost/redweb` or `http://localhost/greenweb`. Could you please review the `nginx.conf` file and give me your comments?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use subfolders instead of the domain it self, it's easy to configure but there's a problem in some cases, the URI will be prepended with the website name.

so if all you are using is static `html` pages or direct `php` files it would be fine, but if you are using something like a framework and that framework is using the URI for routing then there would be some problems because the routes would not match.

for example if you visit `http://localhost/redweb/homepage` the URI would be `/redweb/homepage` but the actual URI the website should be seeing is `/homepage`, to fix it you would need to create a rewrite for each website.

you can try this and if it doesn't work then tell me and I'll try to help you.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /my/web/root;
  index index.html index.php;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/;
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't have the static html or php files. I'm using a framework with PhP files and the base URL is set to `http://localhost`. Even now on different ports (80 and 100), I'm getting the 404 errors because it can not find the pages (e.g. `http://localhost/old/` or `http://localhost/recent/` and etc), probably as you mentioned it reads the URI as `/old/` or `/recent/` which are not defined in the settings file. Could you please edit the `nginx.conf` file and post it back again? thanks

Comment: @Jonathan you can but you need your dns server to point those domains to your local machine, or just update `/etc/hosts` and resolve those to `127.0.0.1`